# C# Page Redirect on Class File

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to redirect to a page , done by a handler getting called on DataReceived Event.

FirstPage : **ZZZ.apsx**

```
 protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            string ValtoSibs = Request.QueryString["ValtoSibs"];
            SIBS.SIBS ComTPA = new SIBS.SIBS();

            ComTPA.IniciaTPA();
            ComTPA.SendPaymentCmd(Int32.Parse(ValtoSibs));



            }
```

The SIBS class (**SIBS.cs**) has the following :

**IniciaTPA()**

```
  public void IniciaTPA()
            {

                ComTPA = new SerialPort("COM7", 2400, Parity.None, 8)
                {
                    Handshake = Handshake.None,
                    WriteTimeout = 2000,
                    ReadTimeout = 2000
                };

                ComTPA.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                ComTPA.Open();
            }
```

And here is the handler , and then the redirect function call inside the handler , **also on SIBS.cs**

```
public  void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    SerialPort TPA = (SerialPort)sender;
    string ReceivedData = TPA.ReadExisting();
    ReadData(ReceivedData);

}

public void ReadData(string ReturnedData)
{
    // CONDIÇOES DE EXIT
    if(ReturnedData.Contains("M001909"))
    {


        CloseTPA();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Erro.aspx",true);

    }
}
```

And i get the error : **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.get returned null.**

From what i've searched the problem is that it can't find the current page because it is not in a page,it is in a .cs file.

What is the fastest way to solve this?

**I tried to set httpContext on the ZZZ.aspx page and then use that variable on SIBS.cs but without sucess.**

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: that's not possible. Since the code is in an event that is called **after** the request ended, `HttpContext.Current` is null as there's no request going on. This is one of the reasons why `HttpContext.Current` should have never existed and why it doesn't exist anymore on ASP.NET Core

Comment: There is not another way to redirect to a page? Basically  i have a serialport listener, and when certain command is sent i want it to redirect to a specific page.

Comment: You cannot redirect since **noone** is waiting for a response from the server. There's no active client/request

Comment: João, as Camilo says, the browser is not waiting for a response when [`Page_LoadComplete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx) fires. You should review the [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#Anchor_1). Camilo, `HttpContext.Current` went away in ASP.NET Core because Microsoft finally went all-in with dependency injection. You can still declare a dependency on `HttpContextAccessor`. (Of course, WebForms went away, too, fortunately.)